# Overwrite differents image with background:url?

Tags: html, css

The code below will use a foreach loop a query result that always return the last 5 guilds in the database with their guild_logo.

The first three guilds will add a trophy in they base, that part is working, but what I'm trying to add is write "Lvl X" at the image's top. To be more specify will write something at the red rectangle in the picture below

[image: Guild_logo]

```
<?php
    echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #imgguild {
                border: 1.5pt solid #333332;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: rgba(2, 18, 34, 0.38);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            }
        </style>';

        // $query will always return the last five guilds and can have a diferent guild_logo. For example the first can be guild_logo1.gif the second guild_logo2.gif in that query I receive that, but below I use "guild_logo".gif to ilustrate.
        foreach ($query as $k => $v) {
            $count++;
            echo '
            <td style="width: 25%; text-align: center;">
                <a href="url">';
                    // All the guilds returned in that query should write Lvl X. Also the three first guilds will add a guild_overlay$count.gif.
                    if ($count <= 3) {
                       echo '<img id="imgguild" style="background:url(guild_logo.gif); background-size: 100%; overflow: hidden;" src="images/guild_logo/guild_overlay'.$count.'.gif" width="100" height="100" border="0"/>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<img src="guild_logo.gif" width="100" height="100" border="0"/>';
                    }
                echo '</a>
            </td>';
        }
    ?>
```

How that can be done?

Comment: Use a `div` and position your three elements inside (main image, trophy and text) rather than trying to jam them all into an `img` element? Alternatively, you could look at pseudo elements `before` and `after` which could display text over an image (Though I don't you how you could apply those inline)

Comment: I almost managed the issue, the problem now is that the style keeps the same image to all divs. The code you can see here https://pastebin.com/zk7hN3HC